# $wpdb->get_var - What value is returned when zero records are found?

Tags: database, mysql, sql

I have the following code:

```
$queryPermission = $wpdb->get_var(  $wpdb->prepare("SELECT Active FROM testers 
                                              WHERE user_id = '$user_id' "));
    if($queryPermission == NULL OR $queryPermission == 0) {
         header ('location: noaccess.php');
    } else {

    }
```

When the SQL returns records the $queryPermission variable is set to 1 which is great. However when the SQL returns no records the variable $queryPermission returns nothing. I then want to try and pick up on this and redirect the user when that variable contains nothing.

I have tried "NULL" and "0" but neither of those seem to work. I was wondering, how can I pick up the case where nothing is returned by SQL using get_var?

Thanks :)

Comment: do you have debugging enabled? if so, your header won't work because you're using `prepare` incorrectly, which should throw an error. get_var does indeed return NULL for no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're using prepare() wrong. Should be this:

`$wpdb->prepare("SELECT Active FROM testers WHERE user_id = %s", $user_id)`

Or even better (%d) represents numeric value as oppose to %s which is string:

`$wpdb->prepare("SELECT Active FROM testers WHERE user_id = %d", $user_id)`

If you have any debugging enabled, it will throw an error from your code. Which may make your location header not work properly.

Second, the get_var() function indeed returns `null` when there are no results.

Third, setting a location: header without actually exiting afterwards may cause your header to be overwritten by something else later.